# Como faço uma linha entre palavra em css?

Tags: css

Olá,
Observei em um site o seguinte estilo em CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entre a frase DESTAQUE DE VENDAS existem duas linhas, uma na direita e outra na esquerda, e elas se ajustam de acordo com a dimensão da tela.

Meu CSS é:

```
div.tipo-imovel{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1550px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Só não tenho noção como implementar.